# How to get result from multiple fields added via javascript dynamicaly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have a script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top" class="container-fluid"><td class="col-sm-6"><input class="col-sm-6" type="text" id="service" name="service[]"></td><td class="col-sm-1"><input class="code" type="text" id="qty" name="qty[]" value=""></td><td class="col-sm-1"><input class="code" type="text" id="price" name="price[]" value=""></td><td class="col-sm-1"><input class="code" type="text" id="discount" name="discount[]" value="" ></td><td class="col-sm-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><input class="btn-default" type="button" id="del" name="del" value="Delete"></a></td></tr>');
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

I append with button new rows to get more services, their price, quantity and discount.

I want to show a sum of total price at the end of the page realtime.

Something like:

```
service_total_price[1] = price[1] * qty[1] - discount[1]

service_total_price[2] = price[2] * qty[2] - discount[2]

service_total_price[3] = price[3] * qty[2] - discount[3]

....
```

and then sum array:

```
service_total_price[]
```

It's important to make all these in realtime when some price is typed in the added field.

Comment: Is it possible at all!?

Comment: It is perfectly possible, but are you trying anything? This site is not for make your homework, is to help you to solve specific problems. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve || http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you should consider using a framework like knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/) or vue.js (http://vuejs.org/)

Comment: or angularjs or reactjs or ...  anything but jquery can do this in 10 lines of code tops

Comment: If OP doesn't know how to make the task described in the post, are you sure he can learn knockout or another framework only to make this task?

Comment: No, I'm not good with scripts, thats why I ask here.

Comment: Alex if is only 10 lines why you won't post them or you also don't know how exactly!?